# Table View Number of Rows not returning array value

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am adding a bunch of values to an array and I am then returning the number of values as a number of rows in a table view. This is how I add my values to the array:

```
func getCurrentUserSchoolOrWorkAddressAndDisplayOtherUsers() {
    let currentUser = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser!)
    let userID = currentUser?.uid

    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        let schoolOrWorkAddress = snapshot.value!["schoolOrWorkAddress"] as! String

        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("schoolOrWorkAddress").child(schoolOrWorkAddress).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            if(!snapshot.exists()){
                return
            }

            let locations = snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary

            for (index, location) in locations.enumerate() {

                FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(location.key as! String).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
                    if(snapshot.exists()){
                        print(snapshot)
                        if let dictionary = snapshot.value  as? [String: AnyObject] {
                            let user = User()
                            user.id = snapshot.key
                            user.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary)

                            self.users.append(user)
                            print(self.users)
                        }
                    }
                    }, withCancelBlock: nil)
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })

        })
    })
}
```

I then return the array count as the number of table view rows like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return users.count

}
```

The only problem is for some reason it does not seem to return any count other than 0. I think the problem stems from the dispatch async code above because it is the first thing that is being called in the function. It is not being called after I append all my elements to an array which should be the problem. However, when I place the dispatch async inside of the for loop instead of outside it does not even get read. I tested this using break points.

the following code is mycellforrowatindexpath code block:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UserCell

    let user = users[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = user.fullName
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = user.email

    if let userPhoto = user.userPhoto {

        cell.profileImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(userPhoto)

    }

    return cell
}
```

The following is some print statement debugging I did which shows what is being appended to the array and what is the users.count value:

[image]

Basically, my question is how do I get it so that the table view is returning my actual value of my array. Once again, I think the problem stems from the dispatch async command.

Any help you have would be appreciated!

Comment: `print(self.users)` PRINT VALUES RIGHT? and how is `users` declared?

Comment: users is simply a variable for access to an array called User

Comment: And yes printing self.users prints the array of Uset

Comment: Are you fetching data from server?If so than you `tableview.reloadata` is being called way before the data is actually loaded. Try this:             `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { print("adsfdsfdsafdasfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfadfdsafdasfdsafdsafdsafdsfdsaf");
                self.tableView.reloadData();
            })` and check when does the text gets print

Comment: Yes from a fire base database

Comment: I want to store that data which is a list of users and then use it to populate my table view. I figured out how to do this by appending my whole database of users but now only want to append a certain group of users.

Comment: You have to use completion block concept here,i .e when all the data gets loaded, then only you reload the table.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do read my above question

Comment: It does not work though

Comment: where are you calling this function getCurrentUserSchoolOrWorkAddressAndDisplayOtherUsers() ?

Comment: Because that is the function that populated my user array

Comment: I am calling it in viewdidload

Comment: Are you using swift3?

Comment: Mr.UB the dispatch async is indeed being called before the data is added which I said in my question